# Json_decode , php , wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl

Does any one here have experience using Json_decode for 100s of stream in Php? I need to see if there is a way to parse through these json streams without loading them in memory since they are over 5000 json streams of news feed on my website. for example, http://example.com/feed/json?paged=1 and paged=2, paged=3 , etc

I need to find a way to search for a value in these files without loading them in memory. Just search through these feed pages and if search value matches, bring the results.

file_get_contents / json_decode takes FOREVER to complete a simple search query.
multiple CURL does the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question you must use a stream reader like [JSONCharInputReader](https://github.com/janeklb/JSONCharInputReader).

If you check [this example](https://github.com/janeklb/JSONCharInputReader/blob/master/example/example.php), you can see that in the "process" method you receive a partial JSON, you can decode it and check if this if this matches for the searched term, if not you can free the memory unsetting the var.

Or maybe this other, [php-streaming-json-parser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser):

```
$stream = fopen('doc.json', 'r');
$listener = new YourListener();
try {
  $parser = new JsonStreamingParser_Parser($stream, $listener);
  $parser->parse();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  fclose($stream);
  throw $e;
}
```

The author of JsonStreamingParser has a [extensive post explaining how it works](http://www.salsify.com/blog/json-streaming-parser-for-php/1056).

Comment: Okay so I got it to running but I guess you misunderstood my question. The question is about parsing large number of files .. not Large data files. My data is in bits of 10 news on each page. But I have around 5000 such pages. 

If I have to search a topic out of these 5000 pages, it takes forever for a loop to go through all URLs and then decode and then match the data. 

Is there a way that we can simply looop through all json URLS for a search term and if matches, just bring that news item and decode it to get its content?